# Can I use Terraform to apply the same configuration locally as in the Cloud?

Tags: amazon-s3, docker-compose, terraform, minio

I'm new to Terraform, so apologies if I'm misunderstanding the use case.

I'm developing a system which uses Ruby on Rails, PostgreSQL and S3. Locally each of those things runs as a docker container, using [Minio](https://github.com/minio/minio) to mock S3 locally.

I want to create an S3 bucket with a certain lifecycle policy. If this were a database and not S3 I would configure some form of DB migration which could be applied automatically as part of docker compose. I could write a small script which runs before the Rails application starts and checks for the presence of the bucket and uses the S3 API to create it if it doesn't exist, but this feels like something I should be using Terraform for.

For my production environment it would be great if Terraform could define the Amazon RDS, EKS and S3 instances, but locally the Postgres and Rails pods will both be configured through docker compose, so its only the S3 bucket and lifecycle policy that I would want to use Terraform to apply.

Please let me know if I'm barking up the wrong tree here. There must be an industry standard for this type of thing but I haven't found anything while searching around.

Comment: I'm kind of lost, do you want all the things you mention locally, or only Minio?

Comment: I am also confused on a similar point as the question title states "apply the same configuration locally as in the Cloud", but then the content states "so its only the S3 bucket and lifecycle policy that I would want to use Terraform to apply". It would probably be beneficial if you described what you want managed with TF, and on what platform.